# Android Studio gradle access module classes from library module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have 2 modules in my Android Studio project. app and mupdf.

App module plugin type is **android** and mupdf module plugin type is **android-library**.

If I add to mupdf dependency to app module, I can access mupdf classes in my app module.

But I need to access module classes in mupdf library module. But taking package doesn't exist error. build.gradle files are like that.

Question is this: **How can I access classes and methods from library module that is main module depends it ?**

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.45@jar'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.45@jar'
    compile files('*****/dd-plist.jar')
    compile files('*****/dd-plist.jar')
    compile project(':mupdf')
}
```

**mupdf/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['res']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.*')
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're trying to do and what errors you're seeing? I can't understand your question.

Comment: Having two separate projects depend on each other likely will not work. The build tools wouldn't know which to build first. You may want to try extracting just the common parts into a library module and keep the rest in one or more sub modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a settings.gradle file with:

```
include ':app'
include ':mupdf'
```

Comment: in which directory is your settings.gradle?